# Override Bootstrap Material Design event listener for <input> element

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular, bootstrap-material-design

I have a `Angular2` component which uses Bootstrap Material Design for look'n'feel

```
@Component({
 selector:'inputCustom',
 template:`
    <div class="form-group label-floating has-error">
        <label class="control-label" for="input">Type here</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="input" type="text">
        <p class="help-block">Some error text</p>
        <span class="material-input"></span>
    </div>
`})
class InputCustom{....}
```

I use `Angular2` to track field changes and I want to control the visuals of my component manually i.e. when in `error` state by applying `class 'has-error'` to outer `<div>` element.

Currently when I apply `class 'has-success'` from my Angular2 controller component, Bootstrap immediately overrides it with a `class 'has-error'`.

How can I override/stop `Bootstrap MD` from tracking validation/input events on `<input>` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it finally out, you just disable the `validation` before actually starting up the library.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.material.options.validate = false;
    $.material.init();

</script>
```